# Cannot show spinner in my activity

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner in my **Child activity**. That means my activity is **child of a Activity Group**

When I click on my spinner it crashed. It crashes before I'm clicking a choice (It didn't even show the choices) see here:

```
public class PriceCalculator extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

        Spinner metalSpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.metalSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> metalDataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Metals));

        metalSpinner.setAdapter(metalDataAdapter);

        metalSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                TextView priceTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
                priceTextView.setText(""+parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });
    }

}
```

My error log here:

```
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44eed660 is not valid; is your activity running?
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:505)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:257)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-18 17:25:24.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32670):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**is your activity running?** 
But my activity is running. Is that happens the activity is a child ?

Comment: If the problem was solved, please write an answer and accept it so that this question is removed from the unsolved questions list.

Comment: @mahe madhi are you using TabActivity or ActivityGroup????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace,

```
setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
```

By

```
View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.calculator, null);
setContentView(contentView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Context` of you adapter to your current Activity Context. That line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> metalDataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Metals));
```

should be changed to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> metalDataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Metals));
```

AFAIK it's better to use current Activity context in creating all UI components